# Custom taxonomies not showing up in admin menu

Tags: custom-taxonomy, admin, admin-menu, register-taxonomy

I have defined a few custom taxonomies in my `functions.php` using the following code:

```
<?php
add_action( 'init', function() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Resource Centers', 'taxonomy general name', 'textdomain' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Resource Center', 'taxonomy singular name', 'textdomain' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Resource Centers', 'textdomain' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Resource Centers', 'textdomain' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Resource Center', 'textdomain' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Resource Center:', 'textdomain' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Resource Center', 'textdomain' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Resource Center', 'textdomain' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Resource Center', 'textdomain' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Resource Center Name', 'textdomain' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Resource Center', 'textdomain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_in_menu'      => true,
        'public'            => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'resource-center' ),
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'resource-center', array( 'post' ), $args );
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Blog Categories', 'taxonomy general name', 'textdomain' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Blog', 'taxonomy singular name', 'textdomain' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Blog Categories', 'textdomain' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Blog Categories', 'textdomain' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Blog Category', 'textdomain' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Blog Category:', 'textdomain' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Blog Category', 'textdomain' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Blog Category', 'textdomain' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Blog Category', 'textdomain' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Blog Category Name', 'textdomain' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Blog Categories', 'textdomain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_in_menu'      => true,
        'public'            => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'blogs', 'with_front' => true ),
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'blog', array( 'post' ), $args );
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Marketing Tags', 'taxonomy general name', 'textdomain' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Marketing Tag', 'taxonomy singular name', 'textdomain' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Marketing Tags', 'textdomain' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Marketing Tags', 'textdomain' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Marketing Tag', 'textdomain' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Marketing Tag:', 'textdomain' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Marketing Tag', 'textdomain' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Marketing Tag', 'textdomain' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Marketing Tag', 'textdomain' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Marketing Tag Name', 'textdomain' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Marketing Tag', 'textdomain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => false,
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_in_menu'      => true,
        'public'            => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'marketing-tag' ),
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'marketing-tag', array( 'post' ), $args );
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Video Playlists', 'taxonomy general name', 'textdomain' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Video Playlist', 'taxonomy singular name', 'textdomain' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Video Playlists', 'textdomain' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Video Playlists', 'textdomain' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Video Playlist', 'textdomain' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Video Playlist:', 'textdomain' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Video Playlist', 'textdomain' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Video Playlist', 'textdomain' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Video Playlist', 'textdomain' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Video Playlist Name', 'textdomain' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Video Playlist', 'textdomain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_in_menu'      => true,
        'public'            => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'video-playlist' ),
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'video-playlist', array( 'post' ), $args );
    flush_rewrite_rules(true);
});
```

As far as I can tell, they are all created correctly and are set to public and visible in the menu/ui.  They all work correctly when editing a post, or when accessed directly via the admin URL, e.g.:

```
/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=blog
/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=marketing-tag
/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=video-playlist
```

However, only the *Resource Centers* taxonomy shows up in the admin menu under posts.  The others are missing:

[image: admin menu]

Any idea why some of my custom taxonomies don't show in the menu?  As silly as it sounds, they *used* to show up and somehow they just vanished.

Comment: You probably should post the code where you're defining your custom taxonomy.

Comment: I did, right in the question (link to the gist).

Comment: LOL. Totally missed that link. Looking at the code, you're not using a priority. In the WordPress documentation, they have the call using a priority of `0`. Also, have you tried creating a defined function and then calling it with `add_action()`?

Comment: I used to have it running with a priority of 0 but removed that as part of my debugging--it did not make a difference.

Comment: I am also calling this inside of an add_action wrapper/function (see line 2 of the gist)

Comment: Try it as a separate function though.

Comment: Doesn't make a difference

Comment: This code works fine for me; all four taxonomies show up in the menu. Try disabling all plugins and switch to a default theme to see if there is code that's altering the menus. Also, only call `flush_rewrite_rules()` on activation or deactivation, because it's a resource intensive operation.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed. The function wrapper thing was the only potential issue I saw with your code as I have never seen it used before and everything in WP's documentation has them as a defined function and then an `add_action()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was caused by a plugin--I turned off all plugins and enabled them one at a time.  Eventually one made the custom taxonomies disappear again.

This is the plugin that caused the issue:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/playbuzz/